# Highchart 3D drag also move the plot image

Tags: highcharts, 3d, draggable

I need a way to also rotate the plot image in 3D column chart at the bottom to make it align with the rotation of the whole chart when I make a drag on the chart.
Now the plot image keep static when the chart is dragging. 
Here is the example:

```
options3d: {
    enabled: true,
    alpha: 20,
    beta: 30,
    depth: 200,
    viewDistance: 5,
    frame: {
      bottom: {
        size: 1,
        color: 'url(#frameBg)'
      }
    }
  },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/akoLv4z9/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature is not supported in Highcharts 3D.

Comment: so sad :( is there any work around on this?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea how to implement it.